# How to achieve proper Fuzzy search in Lucene.Net?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have done Fuzzy search in lucene.Net. In this if i searched `Feature`, the `Feature`,`Featured`,`featuring` only should come.But the data came like based on text matching like `venture`,`culture` and etc. `ture` is matched in that fuzzy search.My code is

```
Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("ContentText", searchString));
finalQuery.Add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look on the process called "Lemmatisation" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation). You would like to build your index based on the base form of the word (called lemma) - and the same you should do with your query.

Lucene supports English language out of the box so there should not be any problem with that.

Comment: +1 - A good word to search for to find more information about this is _stemming_.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass additional filters that check the minimumscore property as well as the minimumsimilarity property that can enhance the quality of the results.  Other things I have done in specific scenarios is use multiple different query types and combine the results (filter out low scores) and return a combined list.  This works really well for things like an engine that can dynamically "assume did you mean..." results initially rather than asking you "did you mean".

Comment: This was years ago but would you mind elaborating on your approach? Did you present the "did you mean" in the UI or did you just present search results that was similar without showing this in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set Parser.FuzzyMinSim